# Bootstrap 3 modal - page background with bottom space

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

When I reload the content of modal by Ajax and the modal height is bigger than height of window, the shadow background is missing (on bottom is space).

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Calling handle update on modal fix the problem.

```
$('.modal').data('bs.modal').handleUpdate();
```